# Prioritized Jquery validation before asp Code Behind in Button Click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

New in ASP.net and i want to set the validation first before it goes to the Codebehind in my asp program, because the fields does'nt validate after clicking the button inside ASP:Content

Heres my Shortcode:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" CssClass="bodyForm">
<section id="content" role="main">
                            <div class="entry two_third">
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                                            jQuery('#contactform').validationEngine('init');


                                            jQuery('#contactform #contact_form_formsend').click(function () {
                                                alert("He Goes Here!");
                                                var form_builder_url = jQuery('#contact_form_url').val();

                                                jQuery('#Content2 .loading').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 250);

                                                if (jQuery('#Content2').validationEngine('validate')) {
                                                    jQuery.post(form_builder_url, {
                                                        contact_name: jQuery('.txtName').val(),
                                                        contact_email: jQuery('.txtEmail').val(),
                                                        contact_subject: jQuery('.txtSubject').val(),
                                                        contact_message: jQuery('.txtaMessage').val(),
                                                        formname: 'Content2',
                                                        formtype: 'contactf'
                                                    }, function () {
                                                        jQuery('#Content2 .loading').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 250);

                                                        document.getElementById('Content2').reset();

                                                        jQuery('#Content2').parent().find('.box').hide();
                                                        jQuery('#Content2').parent().find('.success_box').fadeIn('fast');
                                                        jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('#Content2').offset().top - 100 }, 'slow');
                                                        jQuery('#Content2').parent().find('.success_box').delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
                                                    });

                                                    return false;
                                                } else {
                                                    jQuery('#Content2 .loading').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 250);

                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });

                                    </script>
                                    <form action="#" method="post" id="contactform">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSuccess" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    <br />
                                        <p>Required fields are marked <span class="color_3">*</span></p>
                                        <div class="form_info cmsms_input">
                                            <label for="contact_name">Name <span class="color_3">*</span></label>
                                            <div class="form_field_wrap">
                                                <input type="text" name="contact_name" runat="server"  id="txtName" value="" size="22" tabindex="3" class="txtName validate[required,minSize[3],maxSize[100],custom[onlyLetterSp]]"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="cl"></div>
                                        <div class="form_info cmsms_input">
                                            <label for="contact_email">Email <span class="color_3">*</span></label>
                                            <div class="form_field_wrap">
                                                <input type="text" name="contact_email" runat="server"  id="txtEmail" value="" size="22" tabindex="4" class="txtEmail validate[required,custom[email]]" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="cl"></div>
                                        <div class="cl"></div>
                                        <div class="form_info cmsms_input">
                                            <label for="contact_subject">Subject <span class="color_3">*</span></label>
                                            <div class="form_field_wrap">
                                                <input type="text" name="contact_subject" runat="server" id="txtSubject" value="" size="22" tabindex="6" class="txtSubject validate[required,minSize[3],maxSize[100]]" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="cl"></div>
                                        <div class="form_info cmsms_textarea">
                                            <label for="contact_message">Message <span class="color_3">*</span></label>
                                            <div class="form_field_wrap">
                                                <textarea name="contact_message" runat="server"  id="txtaMessage" cols="28" rows="6" tabindex="7" class="txtaMessage validate[required,minSize[3]]" ></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="cl"></div>
                                        <div class="cl"></div>
                                        <div>
                                        <asp:Button class="more_button fl" runat="server" tabindex="8" Text="Send a message" 
                                                   ID="contact_form_formsend" onclick="btnSendEmail_Click" /></div>
                                            <div class="loading">

                                        </div>
                                        </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>
</asp:Content>
```

Here as you can see, My problem is that it goes forward the the codebehind and submit the form even before validating the page which I encounter Errors because of null fields, Hope Someone with Golden heart help me in this problem. . Thanks in Advance

Comment: are u getting alert message that u have used in your code?

Comment: @abpatil just getting the onload message but the button click function is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call javascript function before postback. `OnClientClick` is use to call javascript function before postback. Use following code for reference:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" ToolTip="Save" OnClientClick="return CheckValidation()"  />
```

Call `CheckValidation()` javascript function. It will postback if function returns true.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckValidation()
{
// do validations here and return true if validate and return false if not
}
</script>
```

Comment: will i include this CheckValidation on the ASP.net itself or the Codebehind? Thanks

Comment: You can javascript on aspx page. It is clientside validation.